Electron Drift Mobility in Metals and Effective Electron Number Density for Calculating Electric Current
When calculate electrical conductivity using $$\sigma = e^2 n \tau / m,$$ n is the total number density of valence electrons in the metal of finite resistance, and $\tau$ can use $\tau_F$ (electron relaxation time at the Fermi level) in [1], pp. 218-219. For metals, this formula makes little physical sense because the conductivity depends only on the electrons at the Fermi level, NOT on the total valence electrons (called conduction electrons in metals in [2], p. 3).
Can I use a similar expression like $$\sigma = e^2 n' \tau' / m$$ for metals [2], where roughly $$n' = k_B T g(E_F) \ \mathrm{and} \ \tau' = \tau_F * (2 / 3) * E_F / (k_B T)$$ $g(E_F)$ is the density of states at the Fermi level. This formula EXPLICITLY says the conductivity and the electric current depend only on the electrons at the Fermi level. But I cannot find such an expression in a book.
The second formula for $\sigma$ also means that electrons have a very high drift mobility $$(e \tau' / m) > 1000 \ \mathrm{cm^2/(V \ s)} \ \mathrm{instead \ of} \ (e \tau / m) = 20 \ \mathrm{cm^2/(V \ s)}.$$ I use parameters for Aluminum when calculate the two mobilities from [4], p. 311 and [2], p. 10. But I cannot find a high-value electron drift mobility in metals from literature.
Can anyone tell me whether the second formula for $\sigma$ can be used or not (semiclassically)? And should I use a high value or a low value for the electron mobility when calculate electric current in metals?
Possibly helpful link:
How to show that the electrons responsible for a current have an energy within $k_BT$ of the Fermi energy?
[1] Ziman's book, Principles of the Theory of Solids, Second Edition.
[2] Ashcroft and Mermin's book, Solid State Physics.
[3] http://dx.doi.org/10.4236/wjcmp.2013.31013
[4] Dimitris A. Papaconstantopoulos, Handbook of the Band Structure of Elemental Solids
From Z = 1 To Z = 112, Second Edition.

I dont understand what it is you want to ask. The standard textbooks that you are consulting already derive the correct replacement expression and explain why, and how it is supposed to be used. Only the tiny silver of electrons near the Fermi surface actually contribute, but they move rather quickly. The low density multipled by fast speeds is equivalent to the full large density multipled by a slow speed, and that is how we define the slow drift velocity.

@naturallyInconsistent The textbooks like [1], p. 216 derived the correct expression for $\sigma$ as an integral, but I want to use a simpler expression like $$\sigma = e^2n'\tau'/m$$ by replacing $n$ and $\tau$ to $n'$ and $\tau'$, respectively, which I think makes physical sense. But I did not find an expression for $\sigma$ using $n'$ and $\tau'$ in a book, for me to cite.

That is because such a replacement does not exist; it is instead used to define the $\tau$ using the original $n$

@naturallyInconsistent I don't understand. But in [3], Equation (8) and Section 2.3, the author does use $n'$ and $\tau'$ for calculating $\sigma$. The author says "conductivity of homogeneous materials can be defined by free randomly moving charge carrier (electron) density and by their drift mobility". And an Einstein relation that holds for metals is proposed, which therefore gives a large electron drift mobility.
